# Django why does blank IntegerField's value show up as "None" in a custom form?

Tags: django, integer, field

i have a very simple `IntegerField` in one of my models.

## models.py

```
## Imports

from django.db import models

class UserModel(models.Model)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)


class NumberModel(models.Model)
    user = models.ForeignKey(UserModel)
    number = models.IntegerField(blank=True, null=True) # This is the IntegerField
```

in the views i am passing the number model itself:

## views.py

```
def change_user_number(request):
    number = get_object_or_404(models.NumberModel, user=request.user)
    return render_to_response('change_number.html', {'number' : number }, context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

Now when i use the value of the the above mentioned Integer Field in one of my custom forms, it shows up as follows:

[image: Text Field with blank IntegerField's Value]

In the template i have something like this:

## template

```
<form id="" action="" method="POST">
    <p><label for="user_number"></label></p>
    <p><input type="text" name="user_number" id="user_number" value="{{ number.number }}" />
    <input type="submit" value="submit" />
</form>
```

I would want to show the value only if the value exists. I am quite sure that the value is saved as null in the database but why does it return `"None"`.

I have also tried the following with no success.

```
<input type="text" name="user_number" id="user_number" {% if number.number == "None" %} value="" {% else %} value="{{ number.number }}" {% endif %} />
```

Comment: Does it read Null on the field in the database?

Comment: yes @RickardZachrisson the value shows as null in the db

Comment: though if i do type(number) from the shell it returns `NoneType`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check if value exist:

```
{% if number.number %}
```

Comment: do you mean {% if number.number %} ? as in the case above `number` is the NumberModel instance which ofcourse exists.

Comment: yeah i have already checked it as metioned in the question above. but the `"None"` still shows up inside the input field.

Comment: @Amyth but you checked if it was equal to the string "None". It isn't, it's equal to None. You should check as Like it recommends here.

Comment: @Likeit my bad i checked for "None", {% if number.number %} works. Much appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

When `number.number` is `None`, it will be stored as null in the database. As Daniel says in the comments, `None` is not the same as the string `"None"`, which is why your comparison does not work.

I recommend you use the [`default_if_none`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/builtins/?from=olddocs#default-if-none) template filter.

```
{{ number.number|default_if_none:"" }}
```

This distinguishes between when the value is `0` and `None`.

Comment: thanks @Alasdair i did not know about this template tag. This helps !